# NodeJS: Different two ways define views directory

Tags: node.js, express

In some Express example, I see there are two ways to define directory to store view file.

First is:

```
app.set('views', './views');
```

Second is:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

My question is: Are there any differences for above two methods ? I have run and see no different effect.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__dirname repersent the current directory in which your app.js file is present. Also . also repersent current directory in which your app.js present.  Difference is that using two dots e.g ../anyFolderName you will move one directory upwith respect to current directory.                         __dirname isn't actually a global but rather local to each module.Hope now difference will be clear to you